# Formatting Infinities in a Table

Tags: formatting, list-manipulation

What is the correct method to replace all types of infinity e.g. `ComplexInfinity` that are present in a `Flatten` `Table` format with text that can be recognised by other languages e.g. `NaN`?

I have `// If[ToString[#] == "ComplexInfinity", "NaN", #] &` but at present I must apply this separately to every input variable in `Table` as,

```
f[x_] := 1/x;
g[x_] := 1/(x - 4);
Table[{f[x] // If[ToString[#] == "ComplexInfinity", "NaN", #] &, 
       g[x] // If[ToString[#] == "ComplexInfinity", "NaN", #] &}, 
      {x, {0, 10, 1}}]
```

- Is there a better way to iterate this through the `Table`?
- As a side note, if I change, `"NaN", #] &` to `"NaN", N[#, 4]] &` to include number formatting then it breaks my code

Comment: Something like `list /. x_DirectedInfinity :> "NaN"`?

Comment: @J.M. Works perfectly thanks. w.r.t. previous edit I jsut discovered the `GetHelp` interface ;)

Comment: Instead of searching for them in Google, try this: when you encounter an unfamiliar symbol in your notebook, highlight it and press F1.